# Struggling to get some data from api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

Hi i'm trying to get some data from "currency API" (https://exchangeratesapi.io/)

and this is code below

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Table from "./dashboard/Table";
import { getLatest } from "../actions/currencyAction";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  const latest = useSelector(state => state.latest);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLatest());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {console.log(latest.rates)}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
export default App;
```

currencyAction.js

```
import { GET_LATEST } from "../actionType";

import axios from "axios";

export function getLatest() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest").then(res => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_LATEST, payload: res.data });
    });
  };
}
```

I succesfully got the data from api

```
<Fragment>
      <Header />
      {console.log(latest.rates)}
    </Fragment>

{CAD: 1.4372, HKD: 8.4324, ISK: 139.3, PHP: 55.248, DKK: 7.4699, …}
CAD: 1.4372
HKD: 8.4324
ISK: 139.3
PHP: 55.248
DKK: 7.4699
HUF: 337.61
CZK: 25.186
AUD: 1.6384
RON: 4.8063
SEK: 10.5833
IDR: 15098.95
INR: 77.8265
BRL: 4.7474
RUB: 70.6675
HRK: 7.465
JPY: 120.52
THB: 34.336
CHF: 1.06
SGD: 1.5164
PLN: 4.2989
BGN: 1.9558
TRY: 6.6599
CNY: 7.6102
NOK: 10.1328
NZD: 1.7095
ZAR: 16.3592
```

but when I'm trying acces each currency, Everthing collapse..

```
   <Fragment>
      <Header />
      {console.log(latest.rates.CAD)}
    </Fragment>


TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAD' of undefined
App
C:/Users/82102/cb/src/components/App.js:17
  14 | 
  15 |  return (
  16 |    <Fragment>
> 17 |      <Header />
     | ^  18 |      {console.log(latest.rates.CAD)}
  19 |    </Fragment>
  20 |  );
```

I struggled for whole day long but I just can't figure out why it's happening..
please share your knowledge.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a property on `rates` before it has been loaded from the API.

The easy solution is to check its existence first:

- Make sure rates is truthy (since `typeof null === 'object'` is also true),
- Check type to see if its an object,
- Then access the property.

```js
{latest.rates && typeof latest.rates === 'object' && console.log(latest.rates.CAD)}
```

Comment: `typeof latest.rates === 'object'` is unnecessary if `latest.rates` can only be falsy values or an object when ready.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `console.log` in return causes an error.

You should do the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Table from "./dashboard/Table";
import { getLatest } from "../actions/currencyAction";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  const latest = useSelector(state => state.latest);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getLatest());
  }, []);

  // add here
  console.log(latest.rates)

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      // remove below line
      // {console.log(latest.rates)}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
export default App;
```